# filters.ModelChoiceFilter не отображается как filters.ChoiceFilter в drf_yasg

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Не могу понять почему ModelChoiceFilter не отображается как надо

```
class ClinicFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    test = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Clinic.objects.all())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]